# Allow "wp-admin" edit access through headless WP web application

Tags: rest-api

I have two servers, one that hosts the WP core (server1), and another server running a Node/React application (server2) that fetches posts/pages through WP Rest API on server1.

I work with a team of content writers who want quick access to the admin dashboard from specific pages/posts. As far as I can tell, there isn't a way to include the black admin bar into a headless JS application.

The URL for the edit link, however, is easily constructed if I have the post ID (`server1.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=${ id }&action=edit`).

I don't want to show ALL users the edit options, and I don't want content writers to have to go to `server1.com/wp-admin`, and then search for the page, every time they want to make an edit.

Is there a way I can send information about whether or not the user is logged in to the client via API response?

**Update**

I tried editing the API server response in `wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php` in the `serve_request` function by adding:

```
$this->send_header('is_user_logged_in', is_user_logged_in() ? true : false);
```

but `is_user_logged_in()` responds with false even when the login is cookied.

Comment: What is the authentification model so far? You already have a distinction between "normal" user and content writer or not? Or do I understand something wrong? Or do you mean that if the writers are logged in the Wordpress backend on server1 and then they go to the frontend on server2, they will show up the "Edit post" link?

Comment: @user141080 I do not have a distinction in the client between a logged-in user and a not-loggin-in user, but I'd like for some information to come via Rest API that would indicate as much.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?